# Access combine different columns with similar values

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database with the following columns

```
UID,Name,Field1, Field2, Field3
```

And the following sample data

```
1,test1,UAP,PAD,ESP
2,test2,PAD,ESP,UAP
3,test3,POP,UAP,ESP
```

As you can see the Field1, Field2, Field3, have similar values, and what i am trying to get the following output

```
New Table
Field Names: UID,Name,Field1

1,test1,ESP
2,test1,PAD
3,test1,UAP
4,test2,ESP
5,test2,PAD
6,test2,UAP
```

Can anyone assist me with how i would be able to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UID, Name, Field1 AS newField FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT UID, Name, Field2 AS newField FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT UID, Name, Field3 AS newField FROM TableName
```

Comment: You need to specify the source table for each part of the union query.

Comment: @Applecore You are right. The table name was not present in the question and I forgot to write it in the answer. I have edited the answer with the correction. Thank you